# Django model method to get recursive children in M2M table inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using table inheritance in Django and the base `ModelA` has a ManyToMany recursive field to itself called `children`. Then I have a `ModelB` that inherits from `ModelA`.

The issue here is that when I query the children of an instance in `ModelB`, they are pointed to their equivalents in `ModelA`. What I would like to accomplish is that an instance of `ModelB` would return a queryset of children also of `ModelB`. I can do this using a method `_children` so it doesn't collide with the field name and have it return the correct model instances.

Is there any way that I could instead have `modelB.children.all()` return the children with the correct model?

I know I could use `_children()` but I would like to call it as an `attribute` and not a `method()`.

The reason for all of this is that the table inheritance was added later in the game and all the instances will be migrated to these new models soon. Plus, `children` is broadly used in my project so it would be a hassle to change it all to `_children`.

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    children = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        related_name='parents',
        symmetrical=False
    )

    def _children(self):
        return type(self).objects.filter(id__in=self.children.all())


class ModelB(ModelA):
    #Set of fields
```

Comment: Just to clarify - should both `ModelA` and `ModelB` have ManyToManyField's to `ModelA` (as the code above suggests)? Rather than `ModelB` having a ManyToManyField to `ModelB`?

Comment: @elyas yes. The `children` field is purposedly in the base model so both ModelA and ModelB have the recursive relationship to themselves

Comment: Your model definition might be giving you unintentional results. `'self'` will be evaluated when `ModelA` is loaded. So `ModelB`'s ManyToManyField's relationship will be to `ModelA`. If you check `ModelB.children.field.related_model` it'll show that it's pointing to `ModelA`. The answer below suggesting an abstract model would fix that issue.

Comment: I see how it would fix this issue but the thing is that I need to have a table for the base model hence it can't be an abstract model. This is mostly because of how the APIs were structured

Comment: It'll be hard to get a perfect solution to that. At the minimum you could use the `@property` decorator on your `_children()` method so it behaves like an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor the recursive bits of `ModelA` into an abstract model and use it more as a mixin. See the [abstract model docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) for more info.

```
class InheritanceMixin(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    children = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        related_name='parents',
        symmetrical=False
    )

    def _children(self):
        return type(self).objects.filter(id__in=self.children.all())


class ModelA(InheritanceMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    # More fields and stuff


class ModelB(InheritanceMixin):
    #Set of fields
```

Comment: I understand how an abstract model would solve it and this is actually a good solution. But my APIs use only one endpoint to work with all `ModelA` instances, no matter if they are `ModelB`, `ModelC` or any other inherited model. That's why I need the basemodel to have an actual table and therefore not be abstract